# Angular JS Group by Count With Filter

Tags: angularjs

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);

    myApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope) 
    {
        $scope.movies = 
        [
            { title: 'The Matrix', rating: 7.5, category: 'Action' },
            { title: 'Focus', rating: 6.9, category: 'Comedy' },
            { title: 'The Lazarus Effect', rating: 6.4, category: 'Thriller' },
            { title: 'Everly', rating: 5.0, category: 'Action' },
            { title: 'Maps to the Stars', rating: 7.5, category: 'Drama' }
        ];
    });     

</script>
<div ng-controller="MyController"> 
    <div class="searchBar">
        <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
    <ul class="angularList" ng-repeat="(key, value) in movies  | groupBy: 'category'">
        <h3>{{ key }} ({{ value.length }})</h3>
        <li ng-repeat="movie in value | filter:title">
            <a href="#">{{ movie.title }}</a><br />
            <div class="rating_box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:{{movie.rating*10}}%"></div>
            </div>
        </li>               
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want result :

Action (2)

The Matrix

Everly

Like this
The code will be perfect, only count is not perfect with group and filter. can any guys help.
So main problem is placing the filter over category.

Thanks,
Ajai Pandey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the result of the filtered list in an alias:

```
 <h3>{{ key }} ({{ filteredList.length }})</h3>
 <li ng-repeat="movie in value | filter:title as filteredList">
```

The nice part is that you can use this variable *above* the ng-repeat where you are filtering, as long as it is in the scope of your controller.

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek4w7za6/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this below code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

check [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for the documentation on ng-repeat.